# Shell Script in netcat listener to talk with client

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, netcat, nc

I have this script on my netcat server which asks for name and some other information:

```
*echo "Tell me your name"                                                    
 read $ln                                                                    
 echo "I got '$ln'"                                                          
 echo "Tell me something more"                                              
 while read ln; do                                                           
    echo "I got '$ln'"                                                       
    echo "Tell me something more"                                           
 done*
```

When a client connects to this server, I want the script to communicate with the client directly.
On server end I do : `while true; do nc -l -p port-no | ./My-script-file ; done`

The while loop is just so that the server continues listening even after one client has closed the connection and nothing else. But somehow, I cannot get the queries to appear on client side.

On client side I do: `nc server-ip port-no`

I want the lines "Tell me your name", "I got..." and "Tell me something else" to appear on client screen and the input from client end to be fed into the script.

I have also tried options like `--exec`, `-e` and `--sh-exec` and the errors I am getting are something like

```
nc: invalid option -- '-'
usage: nc [-46CDdFhklNnrStUuvZz] [-I length] [-i interval] [-M ttl]
      [-m minttl] [-O length] [-P proxy_username] [-p source_port]
      [-q seconds] [-s source] [-T keyword] [-V rtable] [-W recvlimit] [-w timeout]
      [-X proxy_protocol] [-x proxy_address[:port]]       [destination] [port]
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so here I've set up a small example:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -p 'Tell me your name: ' ln;
  do 
    echo "I got $ln";
  done
```

So you save the script make it executable and run it as follows:

**On the server**

```
nc -l -p 4444 -k --sh-exec ./yourscript
```

Here `-k` does keep the connection open so no need for the loop you got there.

**On the client**

```
nc hostname 4444
foo bar
```

This should do the job.

Comment: I have tried using the --exec command before and it didn't work. I tried your command and this is what I got:                                                     root@kali:~/Desktop# nc -l -p 4444 -k --sh-exec ./Test-Script
nc: invalid option -- '-'
usage: nc [-46CDdFhklNnrStUuvZz] [-I length] [-i interval] [-M ttl]
   [-m minttl] [-O length] [-P proxy_username] [-p source_port]
   [-q seconds] [-s source] [-T keyword] [-V rtable] [-W recvlimit] [-w timeout]
   [-X proxy_protocol] [-x proxy_address[:port]]    [destination] [port]
root@kali:~/Desktop#

Comment: @ShritamaSengupta what version of netcat are you using? Does `nc --help` show you the option `--sh-exec` ?

Comment: I got this:nc -h
OpenBSD netcat (Debian patchlevel 1.195-1)

Comment: @ShritamaSengupta your `nc` doesn't support the exec flag the. There is this answer here but it uses `named pipes`  https://superuser.com/questions/691008/why-is-the-e-option-missing-from-netcat-openbsd

Comment: I just installed the traditional-netcat instead and accessed the -exec command. This seemed as the easier way to achieve my task. Thank you for your hint though.

Comment: Great. You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

It seems Open-BSD netcat does not support `-e` or `--exec` commands which helps us to execute a file after a connection has been made. Since it is might cause the remote machine to run potentially harmful command to the connected machine, these commands are considered as dangerous.
                                                                                                                        As a work around I just uninstalled Open-BSD netcat and installed traditional-netcat server following the solution in the site https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065993/how-to-switch-to-netcat-traditional-in-ubuntu. This gave me access to the -exec command. 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                The command that I run on server is : nc -l -p port-number -e File-Script-to-execute